# How to implement search with many to many relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `many to many` relationships for `job` & `city`, here is my models

job.rb

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :job_cities, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :cities, through: :job_cities
end
```

city.rb

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :job_cities, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :jobs, through: :job_cities
end
```

and job_city.rb

```
class JobCity < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :city
    belongs_to :job
end
```

I think you have understood what's going on. Now I need to search a job based on `jobs` & `cities` then I have tried like this

Which working:

```
2.3.4 :002 > city = City.find_by_name('Madrid')
  City Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "cities".* FROM "cities" WHERE "cities"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["name", "Madrid"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<City id: 3, name: "Madrid", created_at: "2017-11-15 13:33:41", updated_at: "2017-11-15 13:33:41", jobs_count: 1, companies_count: 0> 
2.3.4 :003 > jobs = Job.includes(:cities).where('job_cities.city_id' => city.id)
  SQL (0.5ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT "jobs"."id" FROM "jobs" LEFT OUTER JOIN "job_cities" ON "job_cities"."job_id" = "jobs"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "cities" ON "cities"."id" = "job_cities"."city_id" WHERE "job_cities"."city_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["city_id", 3], ["LIMIT", 11]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  SELECT "jobs"."id" AS t0_r0, "jobs"."title" AS t0_r1, "jobs"."details" AS t0_r2, "jobs"."location" AS t0_r3, "jobs"."no_of_vacancies" AS t0_r4, "jobs"."age_range" AS t0_r5, "jobs"."salary_range" AS t0_r6, "jobs"."requirements" AS t0_r7, "jobs"."qualifications" AS t0_r8, "jobs"."additional_qualifications" AS t0_r9, "jobs"."label" AS t0_r10, "jobs"."deadline" AS t0_r11, "jobs"."years_of_experience" AS t0_r12, "jobs"."tags" AS t0_r13, "jobs"."email_for_receive_cv" AS t0_r14, "jobs"."view_count" AS t0_r15, "jobs"."urgency" AS t0_r16, "jobs"."status" AS t0_r17, "jobs"."company_id" AS t0_r18, "jobs"."employer_id" AS t0_r19, "jobs"."created_at" AS t0_r20, "jobs"."updated_at" AS t0_r21, "jobs"."is_hb_apply" AS t0_r22, "jobs"."job_id" AS t0_r23, "jobs"."closed" AS t0_r24, "cities"."id" AS t1_r0, "cities"."name" AS t1_r1, "cities"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "cities"."updated_at" AS t1_r3, "cities"."jobs_count" AS t1_r4, "cities"."companies_count" AS t1_r5 FROM "jobs" LEFT OUTER JOIN "job_cities" ON "job_cities"."job_id" = "jobs"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "cities" ON "cities"."id" = "job_cities"."city_id" WHERE "job_cities"."city_id" = ? AND "jobs"."id" = 6  [["city_id", 3]]

 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Job id: 6, title: "Android Developer", ...........>]>
```

Which not working

```
2.3.4 :004 > city_not_matched = City.find_by_name('madrid')
  City Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "cities".* FROM "cities" WHERE "cities"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["name", "madrid"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => nil 
2.3.4 :005 > jobs = Job.includes(:cities).where('job_cities.city_id' => city_not_matched.id)
NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
        from (irb):5
```

It was tried with the console, the same code I have in search controller like this

```
@city = City.find_by_name(params[:city])
@jobs = Job.includes(:cities).where('job_cities.city_id' => @city.id)
```

The summary is when city name exactly matched then search working otherwise showing

> NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

I knew can't find the city name that's why this error, that is not a right way for search, but how to.

***My question is:*** How can search with `many to many` associations, I want to implement `like` keyword search without any error.

***Note:*** Please don't advise any gem.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
Job.joins(:cities)
   .where("cities.name ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:city]}%")
```

Comment: It's working :), can you explain, please `includes` vs `joins`, I have tried this query using `includes` but not work.

Comment: Thanks So much :)

Comment: `include` is used to minimize the number of database queries (to avoid the so-called _N+1 query_ problem). It does not necessarily just perform just one database query. Usually, it does two queries. `joins` generates a SQL query with an `INNER JOIN`. You need to `JOIN` two tables if you want to return records from one table with a condition on the other. Both (`joins` and `includes`) serve different purposes and aren't interchangeable. You might want to read [this blog post](http://tomdallimore.com/blog/includes-vs-joins-in-rails-when-and-where/) or the Rails Guide.

Comment: @spickermann Shouldn't we use `uniq` keyword as i heard that `joins`  can have duplicate rows?